# Proto "Multiple declaration of i" error on Solaris

Tags: c++, solaris, protocol-buffers

I am trying to build a c++ code that is using a protobuf cc file generated from a proto file on Solaris but I get the error "Multiple declaration for i".

Is there any workaround to force proto to not generate multiple declarations of "i" or a compiler flag on CC to ignore this ?

Generated code by proto is:

```
 // repeated double Prices = 22;
  for (int i = 0; i < this->prices_size(); i++) {
    ::google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteDouble(
      22, this->prices(i), output);
  }

  // repeated double Yields = 23;
  for (int i = 0; i < this->yields_size(); i++) {
    ::google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteDouble(
      23, this->yields(i), output);
  }
```

This triggers the error.

Thanks,
Bogdan

Comment: You could show us the illegal generated code, or the input that causes this to be generated; without these things, it's hard to help.

Comment: What's your compiler? Or it's this `proto` :?

Comment: Interesting that it says declaration, not definition. Makes me wonder if it's one of those subtle differences between C and C++

Comment: I have something in my head, but.. there was a well-known "issue" with some compilers - for example, you can't have 2 for-loops in a function, both having `int i` for iterator.. or something like this:? I don't remember exactly..

Comment: Yes, of course, but I want to force the proto to not generate this pattern (if possible). I am using SunStudio 12 CC compiler.

Comment: @BogdanM.: So you want to force a tool created to generate standards compliant C++03 code to generate C++ code from the pre-standard era of the early 90s, which is decades before that tool was created?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: I guess we have to change the compiler if there is no workaround.

Comment: @BogdanM.: Since now C++11 is out, using a compiler that supports at least C++98 seems reasonable. Doesn't gcc run on your platform?

Comment: gcc runs on Solaris but it the last option. If we do this we have to make a full regression testing on the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of the compiler are you using?  If you specify `-features=localfor`, you should have the correct behavior, but at least in the current versions of the compiler, this is the default unless you specify `-compat=4`.  (But if you need `-compat=4` for other reasons, you can still specify `-features=localfor`.)

Comment: The flags that we are using are: /apps/pkgs/studio-12.0/prod/bin/CC -D_RWCONFIG=12d -features=no%localfor -features=no%conststrings -library=no%rwtools7 -erroff=nonewline

Comment: Well there you go! Remove that `-features=no%localfor` -- that's the source of this problem.

Comment: The question then is why you have `no%localfor`.  You're explicitly requesting this old scope handling.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the compiler is expecting pre-standard C++. According to the documentation this will happen if you specify `-compat` or `-compat=4` on the compiler's command line, so make sure you're not doing that.